# SSO Between Keycloak IDP and another IDP

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I own an application which has it's own IDP - let's call it app1.

I would like to establish SSO to app2 which uses Keycloak as IDP - let' call it app2.

App1:

- Up and running, So I cannot convert my IDP to Keycloak

App2:

- No users yet
- External vendor app (not managed on my domain)

Which possibilities do I have to establish SSO between app1 and app2?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One possible scenario:

You could configure app1-IDP as a third-party IDP in your Keycloak. Then set the app1-IDP as the Default Identity Provider in the Identity Provider Redirector Authenticator in your Realms Browser Flow.

[image]

[image]

If app-IDP should control the SSO session alone, you can then remove the Cookie Authenticator from the Browser Flow.